# Circle Geometry

Tags: circles

How do you derive the equation of a circle $(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2=r^2$ if a point on the y-axis is chosen as then you cannot form a triangle and as a result not apply Pythagoras' theorem and derive the equation of a circle.

Comment: What do you mean with "a point on the y-axis is chosen"?

Comment: The distance formula coming from the Pythogrean theorem is true even if one or both legs of the "triangle" with corners $(a, b)$ and $(x, y)$ have length zero.

Comment: If you consider a point with the same x-coordinate as the centre of the circle (x= a) then the equation just gives $(y-b)^2 = r^2$ ie y = b +/- r. It's still a solution to Pythagorus, just Pythagorus applied to a "triangle" with one side equal to zero so the hypotenuse is equal to the other side.